# Does GetType() or GetProperty() or GetValue() needs pdb file for working in the published website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, pdb-files

In a MVC project, I am using the gettype(), getproperty and getvalue() from System.Reflection. If I publish this website, does these methods need pdb file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope these methods do not need pdb file. Assemblies themselves contain that information. See below from msdn.

> Assemblies contain modules, modules contain types, and types contain
>   members. Reflection provides objects that encapsulate assemblies,
>   modules, and types. You can use reflection to dynamically create an
>   instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the
>   type from an existing object. You can then invoke the type's methods
>   or access its fields and properties.

You can read this link to better understand reflection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx